# Why cookie expired after closing webpage?

Tags: php, cookies

When I try to save cookie, seem it's saved correctly, and I can get them with `$_COOKIE[]` but when I close my webpage and open it again, I can't see them.

```
if(isset($_POST['cookieChk'])){
    setcookie('uName', $_POST['uName'], time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    setcookie('pass', $_POST['pass'], time() + (3600 * 24 * 1), '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
}else if(!isset($_POST['cookieChk'])){
    setcookie('uName', '', time() - (3600 * 24), '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    setcookie('pass',  '', time() - (3600 * 24), '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
}

<input type="text" name="uName" class="loginBox" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['uName']))echo $_COOKIE['uName']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Maybe a browser issue? Settings -> remove cookies after closing?

Comment: Hi dear Flummox, No it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie default expire time is the window session, here the session refer to the browser window, not the SESSION.

Here is a example, see the phpsessid's expire time is session in the picture.
[image: demo]

So when the window closed, the cookir expires. If you not want this, set the cookie expiretime manually.

Answer (score 1):

You told it to in your code,
On every first run of that code, the else if block will be executed, hence destroying your cookies by yourself

I suggest if the your put that block somewhere else or remove it totally

```
//the root of your problem

setcookie('uName','',time()-(3600*24),'/',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie('pass','',time()-(3600*24),'/',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```